# How to resize the QToolButton when focus is coming on that QToolButton

Tags: c++, qt

How to resize the `QToolButton` when focus is coming on that `QToolButton.`
I am having 5 `QToolButton`, when focus is coming on 2nd `QToolButton` its size should automatically increase. How to so it?

Comment: Subclass QToolButton and reimplement [focusInEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusInEvent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make a custom class , subclassing QToolButton.

```
class MyButton : public QToolButton
{
    Q_OBJECT 

    private:
         int originalWidth, originalHeight;
         int bigWidth, bigHeight;
};
```

And then reimplement the focusInEvent and out.

```
void focusInEvent ( QFocusEvent * event ) { 
                   resize(bigWidth,bigHeight); 
                   QToolButton::focusInEvent(event); // Don't forget to call parent focus in / out in order to make the "hover" effect work. 
}

void focusOutEvent ( QFocusEvent * event ) { 
                   resize(originalWidth,originalHeight); 
                   QToolButton::focusOutEvent(event);
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Don't forget to override focusOutEvent for restoring it's original size.

Comment: It is throwing following error: cannot call member function ‘virtual void QAbstractButton::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent*)’ without object

Comment: I have main class as name mywindow. so now how i inherit QtolButton, I a already inheriting QMainWindow under that.

Comment: You need to add  Q_OBJECT under class definition. (just under private:). 
About the "mainwindow" problem, please, explain better!

Comment: I have written everything but its not working for me. When i focus is going on 1st button it is not getting zoom

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible via QSS:

```
#MySecondButton:focus
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Depends on layouting and size policy it may require to set "max-width" / "max-height" / "min-width" etc, properties.

Comment: Works better using min-width and max-width with the same number. The same for height. 
I found many problems using just width and height.